# MYSQL PHP with order by and limit 1 returning null

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, limit

I'm trying to select the first row where there can be any number of rows with a common unique ID that groups them (not necessarily sequentially in the database).

I'm using ORDER BY on the primary column which is a fully unique ID and is an int(11) and using LIMIT 1.

```
$orderins = $db->Execute("select *
                    from " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS_HISTORY . "
                    where orders_id = '.$zv_orders_id.' order by orders_status_history_id ASC LIMIT 1");


$orderins = $orderins->fields['comments']; // SEND VAR
```

orders_status_history_id is the Primary (fully unique ID) and also the first column and which uses auto-increment.

orders_id is the shared id that grouped rows will share. The rows that share this id will not necessarily be one after the other.

And I'm getting an empty result.

The moment I remove the ORDER BY, it sends through a result.

Let me also include, when I remove the ORDER BY, so far it's only returned the very first row with multiple tests.

Returning the first row that exists in the database with that orders_id is in fact the desired result. So maybe I don't need the ORDER BY to work or be there. Can I be sure that the LIMIT 1 will always get the first row in the database that matches the WHERE BY or is there a possibility it will return one of the other rows that also share the WHERE BY filter.

Comment: try changing it to ```"SELECT *
                    FROM `" . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS_HISTORY . "`
                    WHERE `orders_id` = '.$zv_orders_id.' ORDER BY `orders_status_history_id` ASC LIMIT 1"``` -- just putting the quote thingamabobs around the column names has saved me before

Comment: also try changing it to ```ORDER BY``` not ```order by```

Comment: @E2017 sorry, I forgot to mention, I did try that and it didn't work.

Comment: You are mixing between double and single quote, change your query to `"select * from " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS_HISTORY . " where orders_id = '{$zv_orders_id}' order by orders_status_history_id ASC LIMIT 1"`

Comment: WAIT try changing it ```"SELECT *
                    FROM " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS_HISTORY . "
                    where orders_id = '$zv_orders_id' order by orders_status_history_id ASC LIMIT 1"```

Comment: @E2017 sql key words are case-insensitive, no difference between `ORDER BY` and `order by` unless you change the setting

Comment: oh ok. kinda new to sql, mostly done js and react

Comment: @E2017 & catcon both your last suggestions did the trick. Thank you so much please submit an answer so I can mark it. I'm confused though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a very confusing languages and the two different quotes are actually very different. You happened to mix them up, which is an easy mistake to make. To fix it, try changing the query to:

```
"SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS_HISTORY . " where orders_id = '$zv_orders_id' order by orders_status_history_id ASC LIMIT 1"
```

it should work now.

also look at comment by [catcon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11430357/catcon)